# javascript FB.api call works inside getLoginStatus not outside

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

Can someone explain why the api('/me'... call works inside the getLoginStatus block and fails out side the block?

(When I say fails, response.name in undefined as well as everything else)

I've tried doing this inside the fbAsyncInit code and in a callback that is suppose to trigger after the init is complete and in both cases, the api('/me'... call only works in the getLoginStatus block.

In both cases I can only get api('/me' to work inside the getLoginStatus() block.

Note: I've not had any trouble with the user not being connected.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    console.info("connected");
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      // this works
      console.info("Name: "+ response.name + "\nFirst name: "+response.first_name+"");
    });                                
 } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              console.info("bad");
 }
});

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  // response.name == 'undefined' 
  console.info("Name: "+ response.name + "\nFirst name: "+response.first_name+"");
});
```

Comment: I would imagine that there is something returned in the scope of `getLoginStatus` anonymus callback that is needed in order to call `FB.api(/me)`.  Maybe you could try storing the values of the response to `getLoginStatus` into a variable in the global scope or the scope of your plugin...then call get `FB.api(/me)`.  Do you get any permission denied in the net tab of firebug/developer tools? errors?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the net tab other than one for a missing channel that I read was an optional parameter. abort of pull 2-act.channel.facebook.com

Comment: I have the same problem... very curious